# How to transform a vector<int> into a string?

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to pass a value from C++ to TCL. As I cannot pass pointers without the use of some complicated modules, I was thinking of converting a vector to a char array and then passing this as a null terminated string (which is relatively easy).

I have a vector as follows:

```
12, 32, 42, 84
```

which I want to convert into something like:

```
"12 32 42 48"
```

The approach I am thinking of is to use an iterator to iterate through the vector and then convert each integer into its string representation and then add it into a char array (which is dynamically created initially by passing the size of the vector). Is this the right way or is there a function that already does this?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

What about:

```
std::stringstream result;
std::copy(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(result, " "));
```

Then you can pass the pointer from `result.str().c_str()`

Comment: This will not include the spaces, will it?

Comment: The space is passed to the iterator, so they will be included.

Comment: Sir, I will never ever again forget about ostream_iterator and copy. Thank you.

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy: You don't need to `#include <string>` or `<iterator>` for this example code. `<sstream>` contains the needed definitions. You do need `<algorithm>`, `<vector>` and `<sstream>`.

Comment: How do you avoid the trailing space?

Comment: You can use `string::erase` to remove the trailing space afterwards.

Comment: @BillyONeal:  You're probably right in `<string>`, but you need `<iterator>` for `std::ostream_iterator`.

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy: Doh! Open mouth insert foot Bill! :) You are correct sir!

Comment: How to get a big number instead of string i.e instead of "12 32 42 48" 12324248?

Comment: @BillyONeal Thank you for telling us which libraries are needed to be included. I hate it when the user that answers does not provide that information, does give me a hard time, and many other users too, I believe.

Comment: I get the following error: `Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::basic_stringstream<char>'clang(template_instantiate_undefined)`

Answer (score 9):

You can use `copy` in conjunction with a `stringstream` object and the `ostream_iterator` adaptor:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(12);
    v.push_back(32);
    v.push_back(42);
    v.push_back(84);

    stringstream ss;
    copy( v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(ss, " "));
    string s = ss.str();
    s = s.substr(0, s.length()-1);  // get rid of the trailing space

cout << "'" << s << "'";

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

> '12 32 42 84'

Comment: Thanks for trailing space removal...

Comment: In case your having issue with VS2015 on using ostream_iterator, include <iterator> as header file.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a stringstream to build the string. Something like:

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator it;
std::stringstream s;
for( it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it )
{
    if( it != vec.begin() )
        s << " ";

    s << *it;
}

// Now use s.str().c_str() to get the null-terminated char pointer.
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding the trailing space of my suggestion.

Comment: At expense of extra comparisons if( it != vec.begin() ).

Answer (score 2):

You got it right, but you can use `std::ostringstream` to create your char array.

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream StringRepresentation;
for ( vector<int>::iterator it = MyVector.begin(); it != MyVector.end(); it++ ) {
    StringRepresentation << *it << " ";
}

const char * CharArray = StringRepresentation.str().c_str();
```

In this case, `CharArray` is only for reading. If you want to modify the values, you will have to copy it. You can simplify this by using [Boost.Foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/foreach.html).