# How to join a vector<int> to a single int in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, int

How would I convert a vector of ints into a single int in c++?

```
vector<int>myints = {3, 55, 2, 7, 8}
```

Expected answer: `355278`

Comment: how would you handle -1?

Comment: Loops and multiplication seems like it would do the trick.

Comment: Hint: `8 + 7*10 + 2*100 + 55*1000 + 3*100000`.

Comment: or a loop with `<<` to a `strstream`. If you want a string out. Note that if you want an int out your are going to run out of digits pretty quickly

Comment: You'd need to do a check on `log10(x)` to see how much to multiply the existing number by.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transform a vector<int> into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518979/how-to-transform-a-vectorint-into-a-string)

Comment: How to deal with 0 which is the same as 00 or 000?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty way:

```
using namespace std;

vector<int> myints = {3, 55, 2, 7, 8};
stringstream stream;

for(const auto &i : myints)
{
    stream << i;
}

int value = stoi(stream.str());
```

And here's a way to do it without strings:

```
using namespace std;

vector<int> myints = {3, 55, 2, 7, 8};

int value = 0;
for(auto i : myints)
{
    int number = i;
    do
    {
        value *= 10;
        i /= 10;
    }while(i != 0);

    value += number;
}

cout << value << endl;
```

The `i /= 10` is the key bit here as it scales the number up based on the number of digits in the current number, `i`

Comment: Not the way I would do it, but probably handles negatives better than my solution.

Comment: There's no need to declare stringstream stream in the second example as it's never used

Answer (score 2):

Using the `<string>` library and the `+=` operator you can iterate over the vector of ints, cast each number to a string and print out the result:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector <int> myints = {3, 55, 2, -1, 7, 8};

  string s = "";
  for(int i : myints){
      s += to_string(i);
  }

  cout << s;      //prints 3552-178
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job. Please care that an `int` may not be enough to handle the number of digits.

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int vectorToSingleInt(const std::vector<int> &myints)
{
    std::stringstream stringStream;

    for (int &i : myints)
        stringStream << i;

    int output = 0;
    stringStream >> output;

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that you need to figure out how many digits each number contains. You can use `log10` from `<cmath>` to do this. You can move the total by `pow(10, x)`, where `x` is the number of digits you are adding:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int>myints = {3, 55, 2, 7, 8};
    int total = 0;
    for (auto it = myints.begin(); it != myints.end(); ++it) {
        int x = int(log10(*it)) + 1;
        total = total * pow(10, x) + *it;
    }
    cout << total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `355278`, as expected.

Here is an [IDEOne link](https://ideone.com/eE6ehf).

Comment: To get rid of compiler warning better use static_cast<int> explicitly

Comment: Do what the warning says.